# CruiseControl.net with multiple languages?

Tags: language-agnostic, cruisecontrol.net, automated-deploy

I just started working in an environment that uses multiple programming languages, doesn't have source control and doesn't have automated deploys.

I am interested in recommending VSS for source control and using CruiseControl.net for automated deploys but I have only used CC.NET with ASP.NET applications.  Is it possible to use CC.NET to deploy python, php, ASP.NET and ??? apps all from the same instance?

Comment: DO NOT USE VSS unless you have to! There are so many other solutions that are way more robust, cheaper and offer similar integration. I am a fan of Sourcegear, but there are also free options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

CC .net is written in .Net but can handle any project. Your project langage does not matter, you can still use Batch, Powershell, Nant or MsBuild scripts. You may also use Cruise Control or Hudson, as you like.

As for the source control provider, I would prefer svn (or even git) but that's more a matter of habbits : from my point of view VSS is too linked to VS and I don't like the lock on check out by default behaviour.

Comment: Just so you are aware, the lock on check out is an option that you can set. So, if you don't like it, turn it off.

Comment: I knew it, that's why I wrote by default but still thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

VSS is [unsafe for any source](http://www.developsense.com/testing/VSSDefects.html) and is damn near useless outside visual studio. And cruise control is painful to learn and make work at best. Your heart is in the right place, but you probably want slightly different technical solutions. For SCM, you probably want either subversion (cf [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)) or Mercurial ([on IIS7](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/mercurial-on-iis7/)). For continuious integration, I'd look at TeamCity first or Hudson second. Either of which is vastly superior to CCNet in terms of ease of use.